# Setting cooking in Next.js 13.4 middleware

Tags: cookies, next.js, middleware

I have an issue writing cookies in my middleware functions.

I have multiple middleware function chaining themselves:

```js
import { chain } from '@/middlewares/chain';
import { intlMiddleware } from '@/middlewares/intl_middleware';
import { authMiddleware } from '@/middlewares/auth_middleware';
import { localUrlMiddleware } from '@/middlewares/localURL_middleware';

export default chain([
    localUrlMiddleware,
    // authMiddleware,
    intlMiddleware,
    // add more middlewares here
])

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|images/).*)']
}
```

The one I have issue with is the first one:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextMiddleware, NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { Locale, i18nConfig } from '@/lib/translations/i18n.config'
import { match as matchLocale } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher'
import Negotiator from 'negotiator'

function getLocale(request: NextRequest): string {
    const cookieStore = request.cookies
    console.log('Cookies:', cookieStore);

    const localeCookie = cookieStore.get('NEXT_LOCALE')?.toString();
    if (localeCookie) {
        console.log('Locale cookie:', localeCookie);
        return localeCookie
    }

    const negotiatorHeaders: Record<string, string> = {}
    request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value))
    console.log('Negotiator headers:', negotiatorHeaders);

    // @ts-ignore locales are readonly
    const locales: string[] = i18nConfig.locales
    const languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages()
    console.log('Preferred languages:', languages);


    const locale = matchLocale(languages, locales, i18nConfig.defaultLocale)
    console.log('Matched locale:', locale);
    cookieStore.set({
        name: 'NEXT_LOCALE',
        value: locale,
    })
    return locale
}

export function localUrlMiddleware(nextMiddleware: NextMiddleware) {
    return async (request: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) => {
        console.log('localUrl middleware called!');
        const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname
        console.log('pathname:', pathname)

        const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18nConfig.locales.every(
            locale => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
        )

        // Redirect if there is no locale
        if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
            const locale = getLocale(request)
            console.log('missing locale in url, attributing one:', locale);

            return NextResponse.redirect(
                new URL(
                    `/${locale}${pathname.startsWith('/') ? '' : '/'}${pathname}`,
                    request.url
                )
            )
        }
        return nextMiddleware(request, event);
    }
}
```

The getLocale function looks for a NEXT_LOCALE cookie and if none, set a new one.
However, the cookie is never written down!

Here is the output of

```js
    const cookieStore = request.cookies
    console.log('Cookies:', cookieStore);
```

When user is logged out I have:
`Cookies: RequestCookies {}`

When is logged in:
`Cookies: RequestCookies {"next-auth.csrf-token":{"name":"next-auth.csrf-token","value":"1e7c35197cf1706cdcad5b55529c4712af49fb719893fe744bef32523c0997a5|034e93b1da0508b7543836bdb078e0655c2cca1ef5624145607f5f648b5c8813"},"next-auth.callback-url":{"name":"next-auth.callback-url","value":"http://localhost:3000/"},"next-auth.session-token":{"name":"next-auth.session-token","value":"eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..hush7RTHSXT_bw6_.onjonce2DiODfa32mghhdaZttzTKWC8EwODsWE7rl5jDjy8L8LyNAFdHlWoSxUQMEuu8_LcKZI1u9quaR1YRf8M_1JX51DG_Ta42F7QnS3BTXHGJE1ISQLDUCeDLoDz8B6EKxU0CvgPK_DizrryO5_bU9cTDUr6EbsUcIBbP_u-DDgzNjvO1Teqk2g23vF5pXmsN4EHMpz866OiP-hHg86XlHFnZM19Rdqqo0QkFSDpNo6iAyOsj3y1R6VD-4b7r5A5evEEkBcBZjXvDKyRSCtxA4XfY-MoJJakQy1XRrv_h-ueBxStMkO3EPIdOosbC60AG-WeIi5oBf_PBzOFILk8PDiOs1_KTkLKIYx59WUxUs7ph8ExUhcbMvqZR8cR4UiO0.fCFvcQxGWWqK5sc3XSFDQg"}}`

I think the error is my way of interpreting the cookies that makes the writting failed, but I don't know how to fix...

Could you help me please?